# Can anybody help with this matrices problem?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I am home schooling my child at the moment due to the covid-19. He's doing well in his Maths lessons and his tutor has asked him to self-study some matrices, I have no background in mathematics past A-levels, however I have been interested in his work and have been attempting some of the questions and topics he's set myself as a pass time in the evening.

He presented this question to me this morning and we're both unsure how to solve it. I've tried to look online but can't seem to find a question similar (probably lack of awareness / knowledge of what to actually search for). If anybody could show me a step by step on how to solve this it would be great.

"Let $a = 5, b = 9.$

Consider the following system of equations, where λ is some scalar:

$ax − 3az = −3a$

$−2x − λy + z = 2$

$bx + 2by + λbz = b$

By forming the augmented matrix corresponding this system of equations and reducing to row echelon form, find the values of λ that imply the system:
(a) is inconsistent;
(b) has infinitely many solutions;
(c) has a unique solution.
In this case find the unique solution in terms of λ."

After sorting into row echelon form. I'm unsure how to proceed.

Many thanks

Chahid

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.
I suggest keeping your problem statement short and only put the relevant part here.

Comment: Keep your question short and to-the-point. Also do share your attempt at the question.

Answer (score 2):

Begin by scaling rows 1 and 3 to obtain the following:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 & -3\\
-2 &-\lambda & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & \lambda & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Perform the following elementary operations: $2R_1+R_2\mapsto R_2$ and $-R_1+R_3\mapsto R_3$ to obtain
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -5 & -4\\
0 &-\lambda & 1 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 3+\lambda & 4
\end{bmatrix}

Next, perform $2R_2+\lambda R_3\mapsto R_3$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -5 & -4\\
0 &-\lambda & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -10+\lambda(3+\lambda) & -8+4\lambda
\end{bmatrix}

We'll focus our attention on the last row. If this row is all 0, i.e. if there's a value for $\lambda$ such that $-10+\lambda(3+\lambda)=-8+4\lambda=0$, then the system has a free variable and infinitely many solutions. $-10+\lambda(3+\lambda)$ is 0 when $\lambda=-5,2$, and $-8+4\lambda=0$ when $\lambda=2$, so the system has a infinitely many solutions when $\lambda=2$.

If $\lambda=-5$, we return $0=-28$, a false statement, leading to the system of equations having no solutions.

If $\lambda\neq -5,2$, then $-10+\lambda(3+\lambda)\neq 0$ and we can divide by the expression to get a value for $z$, which we can substitute back up the chain to get
$$z=\frac{4}{\lambda+5}$$
$$y=\frac{4}{\lambda+5}$$
$$x=-\frac{3(1+\lambda)}{\lambda+5}$$